# Finding a function to fit equation

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find a function $f$ satisfying:

$$f\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right) + f\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)=\frac{z}{z-1}, \forall z \notin \{0,1\}$$

I can't figure out how. I've tried a general Mobius transformation, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: $z$ is a complex number?

Comment: Yes, $z$ is a complex number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\frac{1}{1-z} = x$, then we have that $x-1=\frac{z}{1-z} \implies \frac1{1-x} = \frac{z-1}{z}$. So the equation transforms to:

$$f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) + f(x) = 1-x$$

Now let this relation be denoted by $P(x)$. Now we have that:

$$P(x) \implies f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) + f(x) = 1-x$$
$$P\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) \implies f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) + f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right) = 1 - \frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$P\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right) \implies f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right) + f(x) = 1 - \frac{x-1}{x}$$

Adding the first and third equations and then subtracting the second one from the sum will give $2f(x)$ on the RHS and some algebraic equation on the RHS.

**NOTE:** From how we defined $x$ we can easily deduce that $x \not = \{0,1\}$, so all the equations are valid.